# How can I check whether a piped content is text with perl

Tags: perl, svn, content-type

I've written a svn-hook for text files. The content test looks like this:

```
svnlook cat -t $txn $repos $file 2>/dev/null | file - | egrep -q 'text$'
```

and I was wondering if this could be done with Perl. However something like this doesn't work:

```
svnlook cat -t $txn $repos $file 2>/dev/null | perl -wnl -e '-T' -
```

I'm testing the exit status of this invocation ($?) to see if the given file was text or binary. Since I'm getting the content out of svn. I can't use perl's normal file check.

I've done a simulation with the file program and perl with a text and binary file (text.txt, icon.png):

> find -type f | xargs -i /bin/bash -c 'if $(cat {} | file - | egrep -q "text$"); then echo "{}: text"; else echo "{}: binary"; fi'

./text.txt: text
./icons.png: binary

> find -type f | xargs -i /bin/bash -c 'if $(cat {} | perl -wln -e "-T;"); then echo "{}: text"; else echo "{}: binary"; fi'

./text.txt: text
./icons.png: text

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've formatted your question. It would be helpful if you could explain in your question (edit) what output you are expecting and how this differs from what you're getting as well as a description of your `${variables}`. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more tips on writing the perfect question!

Comment: Thanks for updating this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing `perl`'s exit code, but you never set it. You need

```
perl -le'exit(-T STDIN ?0:1)' < file
```

Comment: @user1164553, Sorry, I made a few errors. I"m tired. They should all be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the problem is that in the svn context mentioned above I only have access to the content. This is the reason why I used the 'cat' to simulate 'svnlook cat'. So the perl script should work only on the content and not pay attention to the filename.

Comment: I've used it with this result: `find -type f | xargs -i /bin/bash -c 'if $(cat {} | perl -ln -e "exit(-T _ ?0:1)"); then echo "{}: text"; else echo "{}: binary"; fi'`

./text.txt: **binary**
./icons.png: **binary**

Comment: @user1164553, Me bad, should always be STDIN. Like I said, tired. Much more so than I thought. Off to bed now!